# Health Kit Statistics Query - Does it include entries from own source?

Tags: ios, healthkit

Im finding that asking for a sum of, for example, dietary calories from HealthKit will return a value which automatically subtracts entries made from my own app. That is great and is the behaviour I want, but this doesn't happen all the time - sometimes it includes entries I have made from my own app. This makes it impossible to use the HealthKit statistics query results sensibly without going through each object.

```
predicate = [HKQuery predicateForSamplesWithStartDate:[date dateByAddingTimeInterval:-queryLatencyPeriod] endDate:nil options:0];

HKStatisticsQuery *sumQuery;

sumQuery = [[HKStatisticsQuery alloc] initWithQuantityType:[HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryEnergyConsumed] quantitySamplePredicate:predicate options:HKStatisticsOptionCumulativeSum completionHandler:^(HKStatisticsQuery *query, HKStatistics *result, NSError *error) {
    float calories = [[result sumQuantity] doubleValueForUnit:[HKUnit calorieUnit]];
}];
```

Sometimes this includes my app's entries in the total, sometimes it doesn't. Simple as that. I think its an error in HealthKit.

Comment: If you show your query source code, people will be able to comment better on the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: OK, I have added some code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Statistics queries aggregate samples from multiple sources.  When samples of cumulative types from two different sources overlap in time, HealthKit chooses one source to use.  The priority of a source is determined per sample type by the order in which they are listed in the in the Data Sources section of the table on the Share Data view for that sample type in the Health app.

I suspect that when you see that samples from your own app are not being counted, it is actually because samples from another source overlap them.

Comment: So nice to have an answer to this! Thank you.

Comment: A further thought, how then is it possible for an app to make entries into HealthKit but also get a consistent view of what other apps have said about the same metric? e.g. dietary calories. Do they have to a standard query and look through each object?

Comment: When composing a predicate for your query, you may specify which source(s) the samples must belong to.  See predicateForObjectsFromSources: in HKQuery.h.